# Why do scikit-learn regressors raise this shape error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, regression, scikit-learn

I have a matrix of data that I store in one of the scipy.sparse formats for sparse matrices, and a bunch of outcomes that I need to predict. Basically I want to fit a linear model for each one of the outcomes. Since the dataset is quite big (tens of thousands) I'm doing this with SGDRegressor. Now, I have my feature matrix:

```
In [62]: features
Out[62]: 
<77946x72239 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1084093 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

and my outcomes

```
In [63]: outcomes
Out[63]: 
<77946x24 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 416487 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

My question is: in order to train a linear model on the first of the outcomes, why can't I do like the following (see the error)? And what would be the correct way to do this?

```
In [64]: reg.fit(features, outcomes[:,0])
[...]
ValueError: Shapes of X and y do not match.
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `y` should not be a sparse matrix. Second, its shape should be `(n_samples,)` instead of `(1, n_samples)`, so

```
y = outcomes[:, 0].toarray().ravel()
```

should work.